# PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest: addAssets() now accepts NSFastEnumeration. how to achieve this?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

[image]

My Application tries to import an image from photos and adds to an album.

But in latest swift changes. addAssets() accepts parameter as NSFastEnumeration. So I get an error as shown in the image.

even the Apple API document has this same code: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHAssetChangeRequest/placeholderForCreatedAsset

What is the alternative or how do I addAssets now?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I did some research, and according to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/), `NSEnumeration` is a protocol implemented by `NSArray`, `NSSet`, and `NSDictionary`.  This suggests that if you convert `[assetPlaceholder]` to an `NSArray`, you'll be able to use it in the method.  And, in fact, this compiles:

```
let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceholder!]
albumChangeRequest!.addAssets(enumeration)
```